# Find out Hamilton's principal function of a given system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

> A particle oscillates in a straight line about a centre of force which varies at the distance. Show the Hamilton's principal function will be,
> $$S = (\frac{\mu}{2})^\frac{1}{2}\frac{((x_0^2+x^2)cos\mu^\frac{1}{2}(t-t_0)-2xx_0)}{sin\mu^\frac{1}{2}(t-t_0)}.$$